# Break Lines by Whitespace Only

Tags: css, line-breaks

Is there a way to word wrap only when there's white space?  Right now I have it breaking one some special characters (`?-!`) but I only want to it to break at the tabs to keep the columns straight.

[image]

Example:

```
gw5g7#IVKNcvP02r    pFJxywU#B-L.Qp.f    u@hGsrr8g.S4,GtR    !t1oa(2%?tb()lML    -cky!YT8-/*xsCfT    nbjAekWZenH8udR8    sM*e@aSM#89C#$4Z    (r6+$]1j9mw)U72+    !V2O2_UO7(mMM6HP    o6u?D&97&QNJ93D1    .a,,hg%vtl[^PGLO    F(v*CP#aJD13_m&.    /9?[OL?ktCmv8gRP    6CSZuRuu98MT3*,R    O/cclHD+HrG4G^h9    JI]edN.F]hRg8,&n    -6S/S9U[Ai]Sh[8D    LM+Gpkk7-BP1pgpR    -XX4EZjb24Kl9Kgm    j!eK#0?i&kwo&ADg    lvZ@)T%xRFYOV#-.
```

Comment: Enclose the "words" with `<span>`s styled with `white-space: nowrap;`, and the whole thing in a `<div>` with `white-space: pre-wrap;`

Comment: Anyway, could you possibly give us some example markup so we don't have to re-type stuff from a screenshot to test answers?

Comment: Hm, my proposed solution is not quite it, it seems `pre-wrap` causes some leading whitespace on line starts...

Comment: We'll I'm able to get it working by making them `float: left` and adding a `margin-right` but I was hoping there was a way to do it without additional HTML markup

Comment: "Without additional HTML markup" is a somewhat nonsensical restriction. CSS isn't a formatting mechanism for plain text, it's a formatting mechanism for markup documents.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there is currently no way in CSS way to word wrap only when there’s white space. The reason is that browsers apply, rather inconsistently, some of the [Unicode line breaking rules](https://jkorpela.fi/unicode/linebr.html). The rules allow line breaks at many points, e.g. after some punctuation characters in some contexts. In the [CSS3 Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/) draft, there are some proposed additions that would let authors have better control over such issues, but mainly as regards to rendering East Asian languages.

You would need to wrap pieces of text in elements (like `span`) and set `white-space: nowrap` on them, or use the more concise nonstandard but widely supported `nobr` element. In the example case, this would be rather straightforward and could be done with a small piece of JavaScript code (or server-side or in a preprocessor when the page is generated):

```
<nobr>gw5g7#IVKNcvP02r</nobr>    <nobr>pFJxywU#B-L.Qp.f</nobr>...
```

However, it is not clear whether the multiple spaces should be preserved and what the rendering context is (`pre`? `textarea`?). This is a different problem and best addressed as a separate question.