# Line-breaks with whitespace only - rather than with special characters

Tags: javascript, html, css

In relation to this question asked eight years ago; [Break Lines by Whitespace Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136684/break-lines-by-whitespace-only)

Is there a way to ensure lines of text are only broken onto a new line by whitespace — and not special characters such as ',' '?' '!' (as is seemingly the unicode standard)?

For example if I have a string;

```
jsyY!m,?s juqu8Tz~n j29@jak?ks9 2cz33#gg8*
```

Whilst there are four different 'word' strings in the above (separated by white-space), the browser breaks the line after '!' ',' or '?' in some circumstances — whereas I want the browser to treat that string of glyphs as a word in itself.

I have found the above thread asking a very similar question — in which it was agreed there is no way to achieve what I want without wrapping parts of the text in elements like  — which wouldn't be ideal for me as i'm generating these strings on the fly with javascript.

The question is 8 years old so I wondered if anyone knew if anything had changed in this regard? Thanks for any advice or pointers.

**EDIT**

This issue has been solved by iterating through the body of text in javascript, adding '' at the beginning of the string, ' ' in the place of every 'space', and  at the very end of the string. This seems to stop any part of any individual word breaking and being forced onto a new line (when having its individual glyphs replaced by special characters).

Comment: Why would it not be ideal to wrap these strings around elements just because you're generating strings on the fly? This operation should be trivial when handled correctly, i.e. you're not generating a string that's hundreds of thousands of characters long, you're not generating a new string every millisecond or the likes.

Comment: Typically, new browsers should only break words in (non-editable) elements if there is not enough space to fit a whole word in a line. While there are exceptions for specific Unicode characters, '!' ',' or '?' are not among those.

Comment: @Terry I want the option to apply the desired effect to any string of text without breaking the paragraph down into different elements (to manually decide where line breaks should be).

Below is a video of how the effect looks at the moment. The paragraph is contained within a div with id 'introText;. The JS iterates through the whole string and randomly replaces characters. But certain words are broken when a normal character is replaced by a special character (eg. 'a' being replaced by '?').

https://imgur.com/wH1Z6ZC